# Pour une arme, doit-on utiliser enrayement ou enrayage?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Bonjour,

Il me semble qu'[enrayement](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/enrayement/29731) est bien plus beau à l'oreille, mais la définition d'[enrayage](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/enrayage/29730) du larousse me semble plus précise. Que choisir? Peut-on utiliser les deux sans soucis ?

Merci

Answer (score 4):

None. Aucun des deux et cela sonne très mal à l'oreille dans les deux cas.

Enrayé est un verbe pronominal. Donc une arme...

- est enrayée
- s'enraye
  Ou au participe vous pourriez dire que `l'arme s'enrayant, il ne put se défendre`

par exemple. **Mais en aucun cas** enrayement.

La définition du Larousse que vous pointez, est relative au verbe enrayer qui n'est pas le même et ne s'applique pas à une arme.
Dans ce cas il s'agit d'empêcher quelque chose.

De mon point de vue, enrayage n'est ni élégant ni usité dans le cas des armes.

Comment: "Mettre de la graisse dans votre arme réduit ses chances d'enrayement/enrayage de 50% pendant deux jours." ?

Comment: « Graisser (ou plutôt lubrifier ?) votre arme réduit de 50% les risques qu'elle ne s'enraye les deux jours suivants. »

Comment: "L'arme a explosé à cause d'un enrayement/enrayage interne"

Comment: @JulianColin « L'arme a explosé, son mécanisme interne s'étant enrayé ». À peu près personne ne dit enrayement/enrayage.

Comment: @jlliagre là ou je voulais en venir c'est que les termes utilisés sont corrects, répondre de n'utiliser aucun des deux quand la question est de savoir lequel correspond mieux c'est comme dire qu'entre vanille et chocolat il vaut mieux choisir fraise. En plus dans les films le mot enrayement est parfois employé même si peu courant.

Comment: Non vanille, chocolat et fraise ne sont pas comparables à enrayage, enrayement et enrayer. D'une part ils ne partagent pas la même racine et d'autre part, ils sont tous trois très courants. Il vaut mieux être compris que choisir un mot inusité. Enrayage risque d'être pris pour embrayage mal prononcé et enrayement risque d'être pris pour un barbarisme.

Answer (score 4):

Selon le [CNRTL>TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/enrayage), enrayage s'emploie très bien pour une arme à feu :

> − P. anal. Arrêt survenant dans le fonctionnement d'une machine automatique, en particulier d'une arme à feu. Les mitrailleuses ennemies tirent bande sur bande. Une s'arrête, non, c'est un enrayage; elle reprend (Malraux, Espoir,1937, p. 486).

Comment: > [Correspond à enrayer2] Action d'enrayer. Synon. enrayement.
Du coup les deux s'utilisent tout à fait ^^

Answer (score 2):

Enrayement est un terme tout à fait utilisable.

> L'enrayement de l'arme est dû à une erreur de conception.

Il est pas déconseillé de l'utiliser, mais il est effectivement peu pratiqué. On le trouvera plus souvent (pour le cas des armes) utilisé par des avocats, ou de manière générale dans une discussion particulièrement formelle.

Dans les conversations plus courantes le verbe enrayer est préférable.

Pour ce qui est d'enrayage malheureusement je ne connaissais même pas l'existence de ce mot ... mais le CNRTL semble indiquer que c'est un synonyme d'enrayement. Il vaudrait probablement mieux préférer utiliser enrayement donc qui est moins rare.